# How to correctly extend an AEM out of box image component?

Tags: aem, web-component

[image]I have a requirement of creating a custom image component.I need to add a new tab on image component.so, I overridden the cq:dialogue and using the out of box as a super type. OOB image component don't have a tab so I restructured the whole cq:dialogue into two different tab.one of them contain the OOB component nodes and the new tab contain some new functionality that I required.Everything is working fine expect the image preview.when I open the configuration tab and upload a image, initially the image preview is available but when I try to reconfigure it only the name of the image appears instead of the preview.Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm if that behavior is not reproducible on OOTB image component? It would also be good if you could provide AEM version, it sounds like a bug in a dialog that requires some hotfix or service pack to fix. It would be good if you could also provide a code snippet of your dialog.

Comment: AEM version is 6.0. OOTB image component is working fine.Issue is only with the extended component.i attached a image of component structure.
as you can see i restructured the dialog by creating two tabs.no changes are done in properties of that "file" node or any other node.